# What does it mean to use an API key in server-side auth flow?

Tags: python, authentication, podio

New to programming, using Python 3.

I work in sales and want to make a program using the Podio API which is going to take information about potential clients from an excel sheet and use it to create subpages in Podio with their information. To get an API-key, Podio wants a redirect-URL for the purposes described [here](https://developers.podio.com/authentication/server_side) and [here](https://developers.podio.com/authentication/client_side), a whole bunch of text I don't really understand. Does it mean I have to authenticate myself in my program (using my Podio login info?), which sends me to Podio (where I log in to Podio manually, using the same login info?), which sends me to the redirect URL, which sends me back to Podio? I can't really make sense of this.

I googled and found some similar questions but none of the answers explained exactly what the actual functions of these authentication flows are. When do I need them? Do I need them if I'm just going to be using this program myself? Do I always need them to gain access to my Podio account through my program?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to use your program yourself, then `username/password` flow is what you need. It is simplest to understand and use flow of authenticating with Podio API. Here are all needed details for it: https://developers.podio.com/authentication/username_password

To be short: yes, you can enter `localhost` as full domain (without protocol) of your return URL

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So that means I can just put 'localhost' as the redirect-URL?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using some Podio clients, you don't need to think about those things then :) If you are doing raw http calls yourself, then `redirect_uri` domain should match domain from API key that you created on https://podio.com/settings/api page

Comment: I'm still at the level where I don't at all understand what those things mean. What is a Podio client? Do you mean the client library for Python that I've downloaded? What are raw http calls and how do they differ from username/password authentication?

Comment: And just to clarify, can I put 'localhost' as the redirect url if I only intend to use the program myself and can authenticate myself with username and password?

Comment: Please start with reading https://developers.podio.com/, then generate your API key, then proceed with the tutorials https://developers.podio.com/examples

Comment: I don't want to be rude but I really just need a yes or no-answer to whether I can just put down 'localhost' or not, but I guess I'll have to just try and see for myself. I've read most of that, however the problem is really that I'm still at a level where the language on your website is too cryptic (which I understand is due to my own lack of knowledge) and since there's this thing that is required to even get access to the platform (the redirect URL) it would have been helpful to just get a clear answer on what to type in that box. That way I could just get the key and start learning quicker

Comment: yes, you can enter `localhost` as full domain (without protocol) of your return URL